# "cannot find -lreadline" error when compiling Lua

Tags: linux, makefile, installation

This should be a pretty straightforward issue -- I'm trying to compile Lua (or rather lua-vec, which is a minor variant) on a CentOS Linux install, and I get the following error:

```
[jt@flyboy src]#make linux
make all MYCFLAGS=-DLUA_USE_LINUX MYLIBS="-Wl,-E -ldl -lreadline -lhistory -lncurses"
make[1]: Entering directory `/jt/flyboy/fly/lua/lua-vec/src'
gcc -o lua  lua.o liblua.a -lm -Wl,-E -ldl -lreadline -lhistory -lncurses
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lreadline
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [lua] Error 1
```

That would suggest the readline lib is not installed.  But...

```
[jt@flyboy src]#ls /usr/lib/libreadline*
/usr/lib/libreadline.so.5  /usr/lib/libreadline.so.5.1
```

Interestingly, if I rearrange the order of readline/history/ncurses, whichever is first triggers the same error, so I suspect that this is some sort of a folder-specification problem, not a missing library problem.

Any ideas?

---

```
yum install readline-devel.x86_64 readline-devel.i386 ncurses-devel.i386 ncurses-devel.x86_64
```

seems to have done the trick!  The odd thing is I have compiled this before without these libs...  but enough time pondering life's mysteries...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`libreadline` is not enough, it will give you libraries related to readline. You need `libreadline-dev` for compiling package which depends upon `readline` like in above case.

In Red Hat like distros, name of package is `readline-devel`

Following command will do the trick in such environment:

```
$ yum install -y readline-devel
```

Comment: The package names are different on CentOS.  I had actually tried this solution earlier, but got tripped up by the different names -- see my posted solution for the correct ones.

Comment: Thank you mcandre, I have resolved the same question based on your solution. But where the source code to download?

Answer (score 5):

If somebody has this issue in ubuntu/debian:

```
sudo apt-get  install libreadline-dev
```